# increse number value each time its looped

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I think I somehow messed up on the way and made things more complicated than it actually is, so here it goes...  So if anyone got a hint on how I should do instead I would be glad.

At first I got an array

```
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

My problem here was that I wanted an a tag inside every array value, which I found out wasn't so easy. So i did like this:

```
const cool = '<a href="coolLink?id=1">Cool link</a>';
```

And here comes my loop:

```
  cars.forEach(function(e, index){
    $('.row')[index].append(e);
    $('.row')[index].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend' , cool);
  });
```

So I was able to make it work, my cool links works as intended. However as you might see in my href I currently got an id there. All cars should have an unique id. Is there anyway I can +1 the id everytime it gets looped? Or can I acheive this in another way? Like this which doesn't work:

```
const cars = ["Saab<a href="coolLink?id=1">Cool link</a>", "Volvo<a href="coolLink?id=2">Cool link</a>", "BMW<a href="coolLink?id=3">Cool link</a>"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `cool` inside the "loop" then you can make use of the `index` when defining it, for example:

```
cars.forEach(function(e, index){
  const cool = `<a href="coolLink?id=${index + 1}">Cool link</a>`;
  $('.row')[index].append(e);
  $('.row')[index].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend' , cool);
});
```

Comment: ahhhhhh, that was simpler than I thought. Thanks alot for your answer!

Comment: @Jacktheman - Note that this solution is using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  It requires back-ticks and the $ in this case is not jQuery.  +1

Comment: @Yogi Thanks for the clarification haven't used Template Literals before so I'l look into it